# What is the difference between the studentized and non-studentized Breusch-Pagan test?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

I have a multiple regression model with 4 independent variable. I want to test heteroscedasticity with the Breusch-Pagan test. If I do a studentized BP test the p-value is 0,173, with a non-studentized test, it is 0,89.