# What is the difference between these two Breusch-Pagan Tests?

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, assumptions, breusch-pagan

Using R on some data and trying to see whether or not my data is heteroscedastic, I've found two implementations of the Breusch-Pagan test, [bptest](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lmtest/docs/bptest) (package lmtest) and [ncvTest](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/car/docs/ncvTest) (package car). However, these produce different results. What is the difference between the two? When should you choose to use one or the other?

```
> model <- lm(y ~ x)
> bp <- bptest(model)
> bp
studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  model 
BP = 3.3596, df = 1, p-value = 0.06681

> ncvTest(model)
Non-constant Variance Score Test 
Variance formula: ~ fitted.values 
Chisquare = 3.858704    Df = 1     p = 0.04948855
```

These example shows that according to the tests, my data is in one case heteroscedastic and in the other case homoscedastic. I did find [this question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82695/what-is-the-difference-between-the-studentized-and-non-studentized-breusch-pagan) so bptest might be studentized and ncvTest might not be, however, what does this mean then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your guess is correct, `ncvTest` performs the original version of Breusch-Pagan test. This can actually be verified by comparing it to `bptest(model, studentize = FALSE)`. (As @Helix123 pointed out, two functions also differ in other aspects such as default arguments, one should check package manuals of [`lmtest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/lmtest.pdf) and [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf) for more detail.)

The studentized Breusch-Pagan test was proposed by R. Koenker in his 1981 article *A Note on Studentizing a Test for Heteroscedasticity*. The most obvious difference of the two is that they use different test statistics. Namely, let $\xi^\ast$ be the studentized test statistics and $\hat{\xi}$ be the original one, $$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\hat{\xi}=\lambda\xi^\ast,\qquad\lambda=\frac{\Var(\varepsilon^2)}{2\Var(\varepsilon)^2}.$$

Here is a snippet of code that demonstrates what I just wrote (data taken from `faraway` package):

```
> mdl = lm(final ~ midterm, data = stat500)
> bptest(mdl)

    studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  mdl
BP = 0.86813, df = 1, p-value = 0.3515

> bptest(mdl, studentize = FALSE)

    Breusch-Pagan test

data:  mdl
BP = 0.67017, df = 1, p-value = 0.413

> ncvTest(mdl)
Non-constant Variance Score Test 
Variance formula: ~ fitted.values 
Chisquare = 0.6701721    Df = 1     p = 0.4129916 
> 
> n = nrow(stat500)
> e = residuals(mdl)
> bpmdl = lm(e^2 ~ midterm, data = stat500)
> lambda = (n - 1) / n * var(e^2) / (2 * ((n - 1) / n * var(e))^2)
> Studentized_bp = n * summary(bpmdl)$r.squared
> Original_bp = Studentized_bp * lambda
> 
> Studentized_bp
[1] 0.8681335
> Original_bp
[1] 0.6701721
```

As for why one wants to studentize the original BP test, a direct quote from R. Koenker's article may be helpful:

> ... Two conclusions emerge from this analysis:
>
> 1. The asymptotic power of the Breusch and Pagan test is extremely sensitive to the kurtosis of the distribution of $\varepsilon$, and
> 2. the asymptotic size of the test is correct only in special case of Gaussian kurtosis.
>
> The former conclusion is expanded upon in Koenker and Bassett (1981)
>   where alternative, robust tests for heteroscedasticity are suggested.
>   The latter conclusion implies that the significance levels suggested
>   by Breusch and Pagan will be correct only under Gaussian conditions on
>   $\varepsilon$. Since such conditions are generally assumed on blind faith and are
>   notoriously difficult to verify, a modification of the Breusch and
>   Pagan test is suggested which correctly "studentise" the test
>   statistic and leads to asymptotically correct significance levels for
>   a reasonably large class of distributions for $\varepsilon$.

In short, the studentized BP test is more robust than the original one.

Comment: However, there is another difference: `ncvTest` and `bptest` use different variables to explain the residuals, see arguments `var.formula` and `varformula`, respectively. The results will diverge once you add another regressor to your example.

Answer (score 4):

In practical terms, `ncvTest` uses the left-hand-side of the equation and `bptest` uses the right-hand-side, by default.

It means that in a case of `Y ~ X`, both tests will provide the same results (regarding the `studentize = F` option of `bptest`). But in a multivariate analysis such as `Y ~ X1 + X2`, the results will be different. (As @Helix123 pointed out)

From the help file of `ncvTest : var.formula` : "a one-sided formula for the error variance; if omitted, the error variance depends on *the fitted values*." Which means that, by default, the fitted values will be used, but it also allows to use a linear combination of the independent variables (X1 + X2).

From the help file of `bptest : varformula` : "By default *the same explanatory variables* are taken as in the main regression model."

Continuing the same example of @Francis (data `stat500`, from `faraway` package):

```
> mdl_t = lm(final ~ midterm + hw, data = stat500)
```

BP test, using fitted values:

```
> ncvTest(mdl_t) # Default

Non-constant Variance Score Test 
Variance formula: ~ fitted.values 
Chisquare = 0.6509135    Df = 1     p = 0.4197863 

> bptest(mdl_t, varformula = ~ fitted.values(mdl_t), studentize = F)

Breusch-Pagan test

data:  mdl_t
BP = 0.65091, df = 1, p-value = 0.4198
```

BP test, using a linear combination of predictors:

```
> ncvTest(mdl_t, var.formula = ~ midterm + hw)
Non-constant Variance Score Test 
Variance formula: ~ midterm + hw 
Chisquare = 0.7689743    Df = 2     p = 0.6807997 

> bptest(mdl_t, studentize = F) # Default

Breusch-Pagan test

data:  mdl_t
BP = 0.76897, df = 2, p-value = 0.6808
```

The "linear combination option" allows to investigate heteroskedasticity associated to linear dependence of a specific independent variable. For example, just the `hw` variable:

```
> ncvTest(mdl_t, var.formula = ~ hw)
Non-constant Variance Score Test 
Variance formula: ~ hw 
Chisquare = 0.04445789    Df = 1     p = 0.833004 

> bptest(mdl_t, varformula = ~ stat500$hw, studentize = F)

Breusch-Pagan test

data:  mdl_t
BP = 0.044458, df = 1, p-value = 0.833
```

Lastly, as @Francis summarized, "In short, the studentized BP test is more robust than the original one", I usually go with `bptest`, with `studentize = TRUE` (default) and `varformula = ~ fitted.values(my.lm)` as options, for an initial approach for homoskedasticity.